# How to draw a sparkline inside a kendo template?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="items-template">
<div id='sparklineItemlist'> </div>

</script>
```

in my java-script i have

```
function loadSparkline(ItemSN){

   console.log('spark line loaded ' + document.getElementById('sparklineItemlist'));

     $("#sparklineItemlist") .sparkline([5,2,5,3,2,2,4,2,4,6,7,5,6,7,9,6,7,9,9,5,3,9,6,7  ], {
                                   type: 'line',
                                fillColor: null });

}
```

`console.log('spark line loaded ' + document.getElementById('sparklineItemlist'))` returns null and I cannot seem to access the spark line Item list  div.
How can I show the spark line?

Answer (score 0):

put your function in `<script></script>` tag and you `html` out side `'